# Individual programs running

Tags: programming, notebooks

We have a program in one notebook of *Mathematica* which takes a long time to be done completely. We wish to run other independent short codes (without any overlapping between syntax and commands) in other open notebooks individually while the long first program is running. But we have to wait that the first one be finished and after that others to be run. Are there ways to let us exploit some notebooks spontaneously and giving answers from the short programs?

Comment: If two notebooks have the same context and they use different kernels, it would be difficult to do that. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146673/work-with-two-kernels-in-one-notebook

Comment: This may be helpful: [How do I run Wolfram Language evaluations side by side?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12425)

Comment: Simplest way: run two instances of Mathematica.

Comment: (if your license allows you to)

Comment: @ Szabolcs, I cannot what you mean!!!

Comment: @Shadowray, your comment is the most helpful. It is wonderful. Other links from other people who have commented are complicated.

Comment: In addition to creating separate kernels, as described by @Shadowray, I recommend using different contexts for each notebook to prevent possible crosstalk.  Personally, I prefer Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to This Notebook.